# Short hand for .parent().parent().parent()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function, that needs to get the position of an element's parent.

It looks something like:

```
   function show(e) {
        //debugger;
           var nextTableSelector = $(e).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent();
  }
```

Is there a short hand for traversing up the DOM structure?

Something along the lines of:

```
$(e).parent()[5];
```

Any suggestion?

Note this DOM structure is generated by a 3rd party JS framework, and I'm not able to append any additional ID's or Classes to this structure. I'm stuck having to work my way up through the DOM this way.

Comment: Check this out: https://api.jquery.com/parents/

Comment: @Narayon, thanks, I'm familiar with the JQ documentation. This does not help.

Comment: Do you have anything that can identify exclusively the element you want?

Comment: If you don't, but you know its the fifth parent up, you can do $(e).parents().eq(5) or $(e).parents()[5] like you suggested.

Comment: @Narayon your suggestion works. Put it as the answer and I'll give it to you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't identify exclusively the element you want but you know its the fifth parent up, you can do `$(e).parents().eq(5)` or `$(e).parents()[5]` like you suggested.

Answer (score 8):

So, what you need is either [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) or [`.parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/), as below.

```
var target = $('#source').closest('#target');
var target = $('#source').parents('#target');
alert ( target[0].id );
```

Sample HTML for the above:

```
<div id="target">
    Man!
    <div>
        <div>
            <div id="source"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd recommend `.closest()` as `.parents()` travels up the DOM tree to the document's root element, adding each ancestor element to a temporary collection; it then filters that collection based on a selector if one is supplied whereas `.closest()` travels up the DOM tree *only* until it finds a match for the supplied selector.

**Edit:**

As for your case, you may want to do:

```
var n = 5; //say you want the 5th parent
var parent5th = $("#source").parents().eq(n-1);
alert (parent5th[0].id);

//So, your code becomes:
var n = 8; //You want the 8th parent
$(e).parents().eq(n-1);
```

Here is a not-so-ugly function if you will:

```
$.fn.nthParent = function(level) {

    level = level || 1;
    if (level <= 0) return;

    return level === 1 &&
        $(this).parent() || 
        $(this).parents().eq(level-1);
}
```

Usage:

```
//Apply some CSS to level 1 (immediate) parent
$("#source").nthParent().css({
    border: "1px solid red"
});

OR

$(".source").each(function(i) {
    $(this).nthParent(i+1).css({
        border: "4px solid blue"
    });
});
```

[**A Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/o2otbo8a/) for the above.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.closest()` instead `parent().parent()` then you will go to closest element doesn't matter how far it will be in the DOM structure.

Answer (score 2):

As I've mentioned in a comment on another answer, if you want to target a specific parent that has a selector, you'll want to use [`.closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/).

However I think you're after something that gets the `X` parent up the tree, the best way of doing this is with a function I think:

```js
function getXParent(el, x) { // el = jQuery element, x = number of generations
  var curEl = el;
  for (var i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
    curEl = curEl.parent();
  }
  return curEl;
}
var newEl = getXParent($('#t5'), 3);
alert(newEl[0].id);

alert($('#t5').parents()[2].id); // Courtesy of Narayon
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="t1">
  <div id="t2">
    <div id="t3">
      <div id="t4">
        <div id="t5">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Narayon has a simpler alternative I do believe.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this answer is very late, but there is one more way to avoid having to write .parent() 5 times:

```
eval("$(e)" + Array(5).join(".parent()"))
```

will also do the trick.